# Can't read read trained weights in learned tensor flow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to read values acquired by training from a Tensorflow model, but I'm getting only initial values for weights. I'm using an example code from https://gist.github.com/saitodev/8532cf9e94a9490f75a9bce678751aec only with addition of code for printing values of W and b.
I get values of biases (b), but weights (W) are all zeros which can't be true because learned model is actualy working (92% accuracy). I also tryied to set trainable=False for weights and model stopped to learn meaning that W indeed need to be updated to work. How should I read value of learned weights? What is the problem in my approach?

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784]) 

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

  max_steps = 1000
  for step in range(max_steps):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
    if (step % 100) == 0:
      print(step, sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))

  print(max_steps, sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
  print("W=")
  print(sess.run(W))
  print("b=")
  print(sess.run(b))
  print(max_steps, sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Results:

```
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
0 0.3348
100 0.8918
200 0.9037
300 0.906
400 0.9098
500 0.9137
600 0.9168
700 0.9147
800 0.9134
900 0.9193
1000 0.9193
W=
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
b=
[-0.38804549  0.35967571  0.09746896 -0.28238639  0.03597458  1.31636047
 -0.11613782  0.64165515 -1.42244864 -0.24211763]
1000 0.9193
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())` will initialize your variables at the specified way, such as zeros. So, you will get full zeros `W`.

The code you show is only training a model, not including saving or loading the model. If you want load a pre-trained model, you should add code like this:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, model_checkpoint_path)
```

Instead of initialize them by yourself, the code will help you initialize all you (trainable) variables in your graph which find in the checkpoint.

Besides, the variable(tensor) which initialized by parameter `trainable=True` will be trainable and be add to the trainable collection.

Note, you should make sure the graph you want to restore is same with one you defined, including the structe of net, name of op, name of tensor and so on.

You should look at the official documents: [Saving and Restoring](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model).

Comment: I don't need to save or restore model. I only want to check values of variables after model is trained.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand you. The error in your code is `W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))`. You shouldn't initialize `W` with zeros.  Gradient descent method can't update `W`. Try this  `W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784, 10], stddev=1e-4), name="weights")`